# What the difference between JobLockService.getLock() & JobLockService.getTransactionLock()

Tags: alfresco

What the difference between JobLockService.getLock() & JobLockService.getTransactionLock() ? from practical perspective and theoretical perspective ?

Thanks 
Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series Co,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the two methods [signatures](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/lock/JobLockService.html):

```
java.lang.String getLock(org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName lockQName,
                         long timeToLive)
```

Returns a `String`, which is the newly created `LockToken`. You must use the token in following calls to [`refreshLock`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/lock/JobLockService.html#refreshLock%28java.lang.String,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName,%20long%29) or [`releaseLock`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/lock/JobLockService.html#releaseLock%28java.lang.String,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName%29) in order to manually manage the lock life span.

```
void getTransactionalLock(org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName lockQName,
                          long timeToLive)
```

`void` method, only asks for a `QName`. The same thread, or other threads, can call this method to try to acquire the lock. Following calls to `getTransactionalLock` will automatically try to refresh the lock in case it's available/expired, without the need to pass the token around.

Comment: Release Lock is known but what about refreshLock ? an where i can use and why ?

Comment: Every lock has an expiry time (look at the `timeToLive` parameter above), so that you `refreshLock` when you want to extend its life span.